# How to get the value of radio buttons via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following radios:

```
<input name="color" id="color_blue" value="blue">Blue
<input name="color" id="color_red" value="red">Red
<input name="color" id="color_green" value="blue">Green
```

What's the easiest way to find out which radio the user selected? Preferably something like to:

```
$("color").val();
```

Or something close to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

```
$('input[name="color"]:checked').val()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

but you have some errors in your html (*in the question at least*).. (no `type="radio"` specified..)

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color_blue" value="blue">Blue
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color_red" value="red">Red
<input type="radio" name="color" id="color_green" value="blue">Green
```

Comment: Gaby is right. I mistakenly substituted 'selected' for 'checked'.